# How to Render Dygraph in iPython Notebook?

Tags: javascript, python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, dygraphs

I would eventually like to pass data from python data structures to Javascript elements that will render it in a Dygraphs graph within an iPython Notebook.

I am new to using notebooks, especially the javascript/nobebook interaction. I have the latest Dygraphs library saved locally on my machine. At the very least, I would like to be able to render a sample Dygraphs plot in the notebook using that library.

See the notebook below. I am trying to execute the simple Dygraphs example code, using the library provided here: http://dygraphs.com/1.0.1/dygraph-combined.js

However, I cannot seem to get anything to render. Is this the proper way to embed/call libraries and then run javascript from within a notebook?

[image: notebook]

Eventually I would like to generate JSON from Pandas DataFrames and use that data as Dygraphs input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to pass the DataFrame into JavaScript and convert it into a [format](http://dygraphs.com/data.html) that dygraphs can handle. Here's the code I used ([notebook here](https://gist.github.com/danvk/e81557c88d61e34dbd75))

```
html = """
<script src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js"></script>
<div id="dygraph" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function convertToDataTable(d) {
  var columns = _.keys(d);
  columns.splice(columns.indexOf("x"), 1);
  var out = [];
  for (var k in d['x']) {
    var row = [d['x'][k]];
    columns.forEach(function(col) {
      row.push(d[col][k]);
    });
    out.push(row);
  }
  return {data:out, labels:['x'].concat(columns)};
}

function handle_output(out) {
  var json = out.content.data['text/plain'];
  var data = JSON.parse(eval(json));
  var tabular = convertToDataTable(data);
  g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("dygraph"), tabular.data, {
    legend: 'always',
    labels: tabular.labels
  })
}
var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
var callbacks = { 'iopub' : {'output' : handle_output}};
kernel.execute("dfj", callbacks, {silent:false});
</script>
"""

HTML(html)
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: chart rendered using dygraphs in an IPython notebook]

The chart is fully interactive: you can hover, pan, zoom and otherwise interact in the same ways that you would with a typical dygraph.

Comment: This is perfect! It is faster and cleaner than my string building approach.

Comment: Also, would you mind explaining the role of the `kernel` and how that plays into the notebook/javascript interaction?

Comment: See this blog post for more info on `kernel`: http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/06/01/ipython-notebook-javascript-python-communication/

Comment: I made a dygraphs wrapper for use in a notebook. Its got basic functionality for now, using what you provided as a template. https://github.com/DayStarEngineering/PyDyGraphs

Answer (score 0):

danvk's solution is cleaner and faster than this, but I also was able to get this to work by building a Dygraph String from a DataFrame. It seems limited to about 15K points, but the benefit is that once created, the page can be saved as a static html page and the Dygraphs plot stays in place. Makes for a nice portable sharing mechanism for those without notebooks set up.

CELL:

```
%%html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dygraphs.com/1.0.1/dygraph-combined.js"></script>`
```

CELL:

```
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display,Javascript,HTML,display_html,display_javascript,JSON
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y','z'])x=np.arange(1200)
df.y=np.sin(x*2*np.pi/10) + np.random.rand(len(x))*5
df.z=np.cos(x)
df.x=df.y+df.z/3 + (df.y-df.z)**1.25
s=df.to_csv(index_label="Index",float_format="%5f",index=True)
ss=string.join(['"' + x +'\\n"' for x in s.split('\n')],'+\n')
dygraph_str="""
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dygraphs.com/1.0.1/dygraph-combined.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="graphdiv5" style="margin: 0 auto; width:auto;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv5"),  // containing div
    """ + ss[:-6] + """,
    {
        legend: 'always',
        title: 'FOO vs. BAR',
        rollPeriod: 1,
        showRoller: true,
        errorBars: false,
        ylabel: 'Temperature (Stuff)'
    }
  );
</script>
"""
display(HTML(dygraph_str))
```

The notebook looks like this:[image]

Comment: The 15k limit you're running into is due to the trailing "+". When you have a deeply nested expression like N1+N2+N3+..., you eventually overflow the stack. The solution is to have a really long string on a single line, no concatenation necessary.

Or, more concretely, where you have the string.join() line, change it to `ss=json.dumps(s)`.